# 'success.form.fv' event not raised

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I work on validation of the form. I use BootstrapValidator v0.4.5 library.
I wanted to fire 'success.form.fv' event to send form data.

Does anybody can help me fix this code to enter handler and see alert?

Here is form definition:

```
   <form id="b_form" method="post" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Wartość budżetu</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Ilość (B):</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="quantity" type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" readonly />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Warość budżetu (A):</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="budgetvalue" type="text" class="form-control" id="budgetvalue" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Liczba pozycji:</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="itemquantity" type="text" class="form-control" id="itemquantity" placeholder="0-100000" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Liczba pozycji Apple:</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="appleitemquantity" type="text" class="form-control" id="appleitemquantity" placeholder="0-100000" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div id="alert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="submit" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
                <input type="button" value="Anuluj" class="btn btn-danger" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and that is JS code fired when document is ready:

```
  $('#b_form')
        .bootstrapValidator({
            fields: {
                budgetvalue: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Podaj wartość z zakresu 0-' + GetMax1(),
                        },
                        numeric: {
                            message: 'Wartość nie jest liczbą. Użyj kropki jako separatora.',
                            thousandsSeparator: '',
                            decimalSeparator: '.'
                        },
                    },
                },
                itemquantity: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Podaj wartość z zakresu 0-' + GetMax2(),
                        },
                        integer: {
                            message: 'Podana wartość nie jest liczbą całkowitą'
                        },
                    }
                },
                appleitemquantity: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Podaj wartość z zakresu 0-' + GetMax3(),
                        },
                        integer: {
                            message: 'Podana wartość nie jest liczbą całkowitą'
                        },
                    }
                },
            }
        })
        .on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
            alert('test');
        });
```

I guess it can be because of first field of form - it is no checked during validation. I searched on Internet information about that, but I can not find anything valuable.

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: I wasn't able to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding submit handler

> ```
>       feedbackIcons: {
>           valid: null,
>           invalid: null,
>           validating: null
>       },
>       submitButtons: '[type="submit"]',
>       submitHandler: function(){
>           alert("submitHandler");
>       },
> ```